# Add a character to the last position of a string

Tags: c#, string, insert, binary, numbers

I try to convert numbers into binary numbers. So this is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Geben Sie eine Zahl ein, die convertiert werden soll!");
        int a = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
        string b = "";

        while (a != 0)
        {
            if (a %  2 == 0)
            {
                b.Insert(b.Length, "0"); 
            }
            else
            {
                b.Insert(b.Length(), "1"); 
            }
            a = a / 2;

        }
        Console.WriteLine(b);
        Console.ReadLine(); 

    }
```

The problem is, the numbers would be in the wrong order. So I make a string and add the numbers to the last position. But when I execute the code nothing happens...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a string builder and append to the end.  Much more efficient since a new string isn't created with each edit.

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();

...

sb.Append("0");
sb.Append("1");
```

etc.

And when you are done, write it out with `ToString()`

```
Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

To solve your order problem, try inserting at the beginning instead of the end.

```
sb.Insert(0, "0");
sb.Insert(0, "1");
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but my problem is still the same. When I execute the code, the numbers are in the wrong order .

Comment: Updated answer, assuming you want to add to the beginning of the string.  If that's not correct, please update your question with what output you are getting, and what you are expecting.

Answer (score 1):

To concatenate the string just use the `+` operator.

```
b = b + '0';//add to the end
b = '0' + b;//or front
```

Use the Convert.ToString for binary format

```
Convert.ToString(a, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Insert()` returns a new string formed by the old string and the string you inserted. It won't change the original string, you'll have to re-assign the value to `b`or assign the value to a new variable.

Try like this:

```
b = b.Insert(0, "0");
```

Edit: Changed the index where you insert the string as you want the newest values in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `StringBuilder`
under System.Text
 `using System.Text;`

```
    StringBilder b = new StringBuilder();


    b.Append("0");
    b.Append("1");
```

Read more [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2839d5h5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: ah ok I see. I did a logical mistake, it should add the newest one to the first position. Thank you!